# Using 2 7800 series regulators to get -ve, GND and +ve voltage rails

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

I was wondering if there is a way to use 2 linear regulators in series to get positive, GND and negative rails. For example could you connect 7805s to get outputs like drawn? This is more of a thought experiment than something I actually plan to do (I'd just use the power supplies at uni). Thanks
[image: 7805s in series]

Comment: You would be better off using a virtual ground and a 79XX. After getting enough headroom for the dropout of both regulators, of course.

Comment: 78xx regulators cannot sink current, which is what happens when IC1 is loaded with less current than IC2 sources from its GND pin. In other words this chosen architecture is poor (if not bad) design. There are better ways, hang on.

Comment: @jippie, Can you make an answer to that effect so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I  have used 2 7815 regs to make a plus minus 15 volt rail for some Opamps .So you could do the same with your 7805 regs to make the plus minus 5V you want .I used a 50HZ mains transformer with separate windings which are common .An advantage of doing this rather than the orthodox CT winding and 7805 7905 pair is better stability on the negative rail .I have found more stability issues from the 79 negative series that the 78 positive series.Better stability gives better  predictability.The 79 regulater is featured in the www.badbeetles.com   website.

Comment: Instability can be overcome through proper bypassing (and the bypassing requirements for these regulators are not difficult to satisfy anyway). The alternative you describe here means a high impedance/inaccurate negative supply due to the inability of the 7815 to sink current, which I can't see as desirable.